# Angular4 Display Child Components from *ngFor on Load

Tags: angular, ngfor

In `metriclist.ts` I have an array of ~300 metrics and want to display them in their own view so I call:

```
<div class="metriclist">
  <metricview *ngFor="let metric of metrics" [metric]="metric"</metricview>
</div>
```

Instead of waiting for the for loop to finish before displaying anything, is there a way to display them incrementally as each `<metricview>` component is finished initializing?

Comment: Initializing 300 components shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds. What are you doing in the initilialization? Computing the 1,000,000th decimal of PI? Where is the code? Post a complete minimal example reproducing he problem.

Comment: @JBNizet the project is more complex than can be explained here. Basically i'm asking if there is a way to incrementally display each component rather than displaying them in bulk.

Comment: You can build a structural directive that will render 1 or a chunk of components after a timeout following [this example](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-angular/directives/creating_a_structural_directive.html)